# Playing audio data with sounddevice- Python

Tags: python, audio

I have used the following piece of code to play an audio file using sounddevice

```
import sounddevice as sd
import numpy as np
(fs1, x) = read('Traffic_stereo.wav', 'rb')
sd.play(x, fs1)
```

But I do not hear anything! Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably have to add [`sd.wait()`](http://python-sounddevice.readthedocs.org/en/0.3.0/#sounddevice.wait) so your script doesn't quit until the file has been played.

Comment: Thanks! :-) I have another question though. It doesn't work for multi-channel audio. I get the following error:
    sounddevice.PortAudioError: Error opening OutputStream: Invalid number of channels

Comment: Happy to help. 1. Set `sd.default.channels` to your number of channels. 2. If it still doesn't work, you have to choose an output device that supports this number of channels, see [here](http://python-sounddevice.readthedocs.org/en/0.3.0/#device-selection).